# Is there any way to connect localhost in mobile devices like iOS in browser stack?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, browserstack, browser-testing

I tried of connecting http://localhost:3000 through my local ip address like http://mylocalipaddress:3000, but still the local site is not working for mobiles and tablets.

Is there any way to connect to localhost in mobiles and tablets in browser stack?

Answer (score 0):

The prerequisite for accessing a localhost website at BrowserStack is to setup Local Testing, which can be set up by download their local desktop application from here: https://www.browserstack.com/question/785

Once set up, you should see a green dot next to 'Local Testing' on their floating toolbar and you should be able to access your localhost website on the remote machines/devices.

I would suggest reaching out to their support team at support@browserstack.com if you continue to face any issues.